# haproxy redirect aquery of URL to another URL

Tags: linux, proxy, centos, load-balancing, haproxy

I want to redirect

https://example1.com/?id=NUMBER
to

https://example2.com/ords/test/portal/test_ppp_&lang=en&?id=NUMBER

I need "Id=NUMBER" (which NUMBER is dynamic) to be in redirection as id.

Answer (score 0):

If your HAProxy version is 2.0 you should use **http-request replace-uri**. More information on [HAProxy documentation: replace-uri](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.0/configuration.html#4.2-http-request%20replace-uri)

An example on how it works:

```
# prefix /foo : turn /bar?q=1 into /foo/bar?q=1 
http-request replace-uri ([^/:]*://[^/]*)?(.*) \1/foo\2
```

If you are using an older HAProxy version you can try [regrep](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#4.2-reqrep) or [regsub](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#7.3.1-regsub).